# Sort.score in R

Tags: r

I am unable to run the code for sort.score in R,

I get the following  error:Error in sort.score(AIC(m000.avalon, m001.avalon, m101.avalon, m200.avalon)  :
could not find function "sort.score".

can anyone advice, where I am going wrong . Thank you

Comment: It looks like you’ve forgotten to load the package that defines `sort.score`. I think that’s `dLagM`. So `library(dLagM)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The function is actually `sortScore`, not `sort.score`. Try this instead, it will work for sure.